# What was the purpose of having Zion?

Tags: the-matrix

In Matrix Reloaded, the Architect explains how Zion was part of their plan for the 1% of the population that reject the Matrix, but he doesn't explain WHY the machines created Zion in the first place. Why couldn't they immediately kill the 1% so that they would save the trouble of having to deal with them later on? If the humans are unplugged they are obviously useless, so why keep them around?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Zion wasn't just a refugee camp, it was also an armed base sending soldiers into the Matrix to **locate new recruits**. Ironically (and unbeknownst to the Zionese rebels), they were actually helping the Machines by using their skill and cunning to locate, remove and then *contain* potential troublemakers in one place.

Once the numbers in Zion reach a critical level (e.g. where the inhabitants are starting to think about spreading beyond the limits of the city and fomenting genuine unrest within the Matrix) the machines then step in, kill almost everyone and restart the process.

**Beyond the purpose mentioned above, the existence of Zion offers four main benefits to the machines;**

- It acts as a "safety valve" for the Matrix, collecting malcontents in one place.
- It acts as a supply of humans in the event of the "*cataclysmic system crash*" described by the Architect.
- It helps the machines to hone their defences against the sort of innovative attacks seen in "[Matriculated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animatrix#.22Matriculated.22)".
- The One needs to have lived in Zion for several years in order to develop the "*profound attachment to the rest of* [his] *species*" that will guide his future actions after the Matrix is rebooted.

Comment: The purpose of life is to end.

Comment: It finally makes sense now!

Comment: @fredsbend - Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: What exactly should be 'the obvious', of purposes? It seems to refer to your previous 'contain... in one place' notion, but it also re-lists it as the first point.

Comment: You make it seem like there are exactly four main purposes; but I think you cannot be sure. Nor in the exact amount and neither whether the Machines consider either of them a 'main purpose'. Just as you seem to assert that the people of Zion may would have been unaware of all the noted four purposes, you can be unaware of any more just as well, or actually even in their prioritization or validity. You cannot arguably be sure because for example it is up to interpretation [What are the machines in the Matrix doing?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33728/) at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually answer the question. The OP asks: ***If the humans are unplugged they are obviously useless, so why keep them around?*** You could make it more clear by noting which supposed purpose should ensure that it is better to keep the 'refugees' around than killing them off right away (assuming it could be done, see for example the robot that unplugs Neo)?

Comment: How exactly would Zion actually help the machines to `hone their defences` against Matriculated-like attacks?

Comment: @naxa - When Neo suggests going overland, Roland mentions that they've tried to assault the Machine City before "[In a] hundred years no ship has gone within a hundred kilometers of it".

Comment: @naxa - The "obvious" is using the humans as a judas-goat, to identify and remove malcontents from the Matrix.

Comment: @Richard interesting connection with Roland's. Is there something that supports that they may have been attempting to use converted machines to approach the Machine City before? The machine in Matriculated doesn't in particular seem to be capable to avoid the machine defense line. It is a man-sized robot with the connectivity to jack-in to a matrix. Having Zion for the purpose of letting them convert some robots in order to help the humans attacking the machine city and thus providing opportunity for the machines to improve their defenses seems a bit too vague at least at first.

Comment: @Richard: interesting notion with the judas-goat; I gather it is the goat that pretends to be a friend of other goats but leads them to slaughter, trading that for avoiding it's own life. But in these terms isn't it too broad to say that "the humans" are used as judas-goat, meaning perhaps people in Zion? Zion is not planned to be spared, and they mostly seem unaware of their "self-betrayal" (?), if there were any. The only exact Judas-goat function seems to be the role meant for the One, who is seems to be a *single* individual.

Comment: @naxa - Their betrayal is absolute. Without the ingenuity of the Zionese, the machines wouldn't be able to find malcontents. Note that they only target Neo after Cypher tells them where to look.

Comment: Richard I still can't get this "obvious" (I think it's not) thingy. Can't you please rephrase it in more direct terms. You seem to imply that the machines wouldn't be able to identify - what? "Malcontents"? What's that? Would-be-rebels? - without Zionese. Be it. So what?

Comment: Answered very nicely.

Answer (score 19):

The way I understood it was that Zion was something like a pressure valve.

The Architect knew that his equations will always produce a few dissenting humans within the population. These dissenters could destabilize the whole Matrix and bring it crashing down. The equations said that he could *never* completely get rid of them. So the next best thing to do was to contain them. Give them all a place to call home. So instead of each group of dissenters creating their own pocket of resistance, all of them are now under one umbrella group: Zion. Having all the dissenters in one place means that you can watch them and monitor them. Keep up the illusion that they are completely independent, and they will continue to grow their central city and not venture to split up. And if the humans become too troublesome, well the Machines already know that they are in one place, and it's just a matter of exterminating them all.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that Zion is just another level inside the Matrix. The Machines gave these people the illusion that they are (now) in control of their own body in Zion. But in actuality they are still plugged into the Matrix and are still being harvested of their powers (bioelectricity) so they are not actually useless.

Comment: I actually thought about this. I really like this idea! I don't who downvoted this but I'm glad to see someone supporting this idea. It also explains why Neo was able to destroy the machines in the "real world".

Comment: I downvoted because while the MWIAM theory is interesting, it's basically a fan-theory; http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Matrix_in_a_Matrix_theory

Comment: Fun as fan-theories are, I don't think they're on topic here.

Comment: I agree, it is a fantastic _theory_, not an answer

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Related: [In "The Matrix Revolutions" How Does Neo Stop the Machine Weapons in the Real World?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11481)

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**:
 In my view the main purpose of Zion, from the viewpoint expressed 
prominently by the Architect, is **not** to collect the rebels but to 
*keep the Matrix functional* ***at all***.

At least two initial iterations designed by the Architect were 
disfunctional. Zion must have been systematically introduced when 
another program, believed to be the Oracle, provided an unsystematic but
 functional solution to keep it going.

Since without Zion the whole Matrix fails, its single main purpose is 
probably to allow the Matrix to remain in working order for extended 
periods of time.

---

**proof tl;dr**: if the rebels *were* truly use-less or an unorganized 
threat to the Machines, the Machines *would* instantly kill them 
*because it is them* unplugging the humans from the power-plant, with 
this robot:

[image: docbot]

Since the Machines, at least the Architect-"branch" of them, are 
associated with efficiency and systematicity, the reason they don't kill
 the awakened humans at this point is most likely because *they don't 
want to*.

(*edit: rewording*)

That rules out all <del>three</del> now four of Richard's proposed extra main purposes:

If the rebels *were* useless, they *would* be killed. Thus:

- `malcontents in one place` and `supply of humans`: no need to wait them gather when you can kill them right off. Without the One there is no anomaly and there is no crash so they wouldn't need an external supply.
- `hone their defences` and `to have lived in Zion`: already dead, they could not attack the Machine City, and they couldn't recruit the One either.

The movie-fact that might include an actual reason for the Machines to 
*allow* Zion, is that we've been told the Matrix was *needed to be 
re-designed*. Re-*based* on a different idea supposedly by the Oracle. This idea contains a systemic anomaly - that is supposedly The One. So now the Machines need to let awaken people to live and prosper... because without The One the Matrix just doesn't work.

I think Richard seems to try and convey this by the `beyond the obvious`, only it is not obvious at all. Were it obvious the OP wouldn't ask:

> WHY the machines created Zion in the first place. Why couldn't they immediately kill the 1%

So isn't it "obvious". I think they might did that in the Architect's two initial iterations. *It didn't work.* ***What other purpose do you need?!***

---

I originally had a *very long* analysis but I decided to remove it. Will
 share with anyone interested. I tried to make the points in the short 
versions above. However it also contained passages trying to point out 
several perceived assumptions in your questions. I re-mention these 
assumptions:

One assumption is that Zion should be initially machine-built which may 
be wrong, because the Architect only says that they have *destroyed* it 
six times, and that "individuals" will be required to be selected in 
order to *rebuild* it.

The other assumption which may be the more flawed is that ther rebels 
should be deemed "useless" (supposedly by the Machines). They are not 
becuase if they were then the Machines would kill them when they awake.

There is another remotely connected assumption, that there should be no 
other forms of intelligence on the planet (supposing there *is* a 
planet) but the Machines and the Humans; however, the Machines are 
mainly associated with Agents, Sentinels, Machine City and the 
Architect. But the Architect does not exercise control over *the 
Exiles*. It is known that they can get things out of the Matrix, so they
 can live outside it. They behave clearly very distinctively from other 
machines, the Agents wants to kill them more than the rebels, and they 
are handled *separately* in the franchise's supposed canonical 
continuation The Matrix Online. They can be a third "form"; even more 
lifeforms are not mentioned although not ruled out either.

Comment: meta-update... the "Richard" I talk about is who now seems to go by the name "Valorum"... so it is [user 20774](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum). so now you know.

Comment: Small point, but I don't think the machine that Neo encounters when he first wakes up is controlled by the rebels (it gives no friendly indications, and is pretty rough with him), just an automated drone that checks any pod failures - it examines Neo, sees a human who's woken up for whatever reason, and gives the "ok" for the chute to open, which would free up the pod and drown the human. I see no indication that it is rebel-affiliated.